# Yosemite 10.10.5 umask issue

Tags: macos, permission

I'm having issues with setting the default umask on our Macs for users. I run the following the commands to set the default perms to 775:

```
sudo launchctl config user umask 002
sudo launchctl config system umask 002
```

But if I then run: touch file.txt the perms on file.txt show up as:

```
-rw-rw-r--
```

If I change the umask to 000, which should set perms to 777, I see the following:

```
-rw-rw-rw-
```

All the Macs in question are running 10.10.5

Is this related to the fact that if you go to: Get Info > Sharing & Permissions > the only options available are Read & Write or Read Only? We're encountering issues whereby our Linux users can't open files copied to network storage by Mac users because the permissions aren't 775.

The only work around I've got at the moment is to get Mac users to mount network shares via SMB instead of using NFS. I'd quite like to know if there's a better method.